# If one getopts flag is active, how do I make another flag behave a certain way?

Tags: android, bash, shell, sh

If a getopts flag is set to true, how do I make another flag act according to it?

```
option_r=false
option_v=false

while getopts 'r:v' option
do
 case "$option" in

 r) option_r=true
    *Just to set the flag to true*
    ;;

 v) option_v=true
    if *option -r is set to true*
    then
    cp -r directory1 directory2

    if *option -r is set to false*
    then
    cp directory1 directory2 (copy normally)
    ;;
```

I hope I explained myself properly.

Basically, if a flag is on, I want that to be reflected on another option. If option -r is active, copy recursively, else, copy normally.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I would do it in two steps: first get the arguments, then apply logic. Here's an example:

```
option_r=false
option_v=false
while getopts "rv" opt; do
    case $opt in
        r)  
            option_r=true
            ;;  
        v)  
            option_v=true
            ;;  
    esac
done

if [ "$option_v" = true ] ; then
    if [ "$option_r" = true ] ; then
        cp -r directory1 directory2
    else
        cp directory1 directory2
    fi  
fi
```

Comment: This is necessary as `getopts` doesn't care which order the options come in.  You have to cater for both `command -r -v` and `command -v -r`